# How to do the ESCAPE + "_" shortcut in bash?

Tags: bash

How can I set up my bash to replace <kbd>ESCAPE</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> with the last word from the previous command?

Comment: AFAICT, that's what `bash` does by default (enter the last word from the previous command when you press the Escape key followed by the _ one. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd>

Then lets see whether <kbd>ESC</kbd>-<kbd>_</kbd> works.

Answer (score 1):

In the readline library that bash uses for these commands, the command for manipulating the shell history in this fashion is `yank-last-arg`, by default bound to <kbd>Mod1</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> *and* <kbd>Mod1</kbd><kbd>_</kbd>, where <kbd>Mod1</kbd> is typically <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Escape</kbd>:

> **yank-last-arg (M-., M-_)**
> Insert the last argument to the previous command (the last word of the previous history entry). With an argument, behave exactly like yank-nth-arg. Successive calls to yank-last-arg move back through the history list, inserting the last argument of each line in turn.<sup>1</sup>

You can use either; or you can bind it to another sequence in your `.inputrc`, like so:

```
"\ep": yank-last-arg
```

which would bind it to <kbd>Mod1</kbd><kbd>p</kbd>.

<sup>1. http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_readline.htm</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `!$` but that does not paste the actual word into the command line for editing like Esc-_ does.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction

Comment: Bash provides some commands to perform the expansion of the current line. For example history expansion is done by the `history-expand-line` command which is mapped to `M-^` in emacs mode by default.